# Kubuntu 20.10: Inconsistent scrolling direction when enabling Wayland

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, kde, wayland

After switching to Wayland so that i can have different scaling factors for my screens, the scrolling started doing something weird.

In applications, the scrolling is normal, but inside the KDE menu, or KDE specific things like system settings, the scrolling is inverted.

I've tried toggling this in both directions, when going to natural scrolling, applications are now on natural scrolling (inverted), but KDE specific things are normal again.

[image: screenshot of touchpad settings]

I'm seeing similar issues on other distros from many years ago:
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4slr9l/inconsistent_touchpad_scrolling_direction/

I've tried removing synaptics since i'm on Wayland now, but it makes no difference:

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
reboot
```

Any ideas how this can be fixed on Kubuntu without sacrificing individual monitor scaling factors that i got from Wayland?